# undefined method `model_name' for 3:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I defined a helper method to pre-populate a nested model.

```
module MealsHelper
    def setup_meal( meal )
        add_recipes meal, 3
    end

    def add_recipes( meal,  number )
        number.times { meal.recipes.build }
    end
end
```

Then I added it to my controller:

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_meal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  helper MealsHelper
```

Then I called it from my form:

```
<%= form_for(setup_meal(@meal)) do |f| %>
```

and now I get:

```
undefined method `model_name' for 3:Fixnum
```

Why is rails trying to find a model for Fixnum?

If I skip the helper method, the error goes away:

```
<%= form_for(@meal) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`times` will only return the Fixnum it is iterating over.

Try:

```
def add_recipes( meal,  number )
    number.times { meal.recipes.build }
    return meal
end
```